# Catch all request events in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sinon

I was wondering how one would go about catching all `request` events in backbone. I want do do this in combination with my qunit and sinon:

I want my sinon fakeServer to respond to every `request` event sent by my js.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) to catch all requests.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        // play with the xhr here
    }
});
```

---

Another way would be to extend [Backbone.Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) `trigger` method, and watch for the request event there and act according to it. Something along these lines:

```
Backbone.Events._oldTrigger = Backbone.Events.trigger;

Backbone.Events.trigger = function (eventName) {

    if (eventName == 'request') {
        // play here
    } else {
        Backbone.Events._oldTrigger.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```